# How can I use an ampersand in an arara command line?

Tags: arara

I have an arara rule file that needs to construct an URL with parameters (https://gist.github.com/ReichenHack/0dd80e12870366d5f51f), but anytime I pass one of the options, I get the error

```
'exportNotes' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I obviously need to quote the '&' but I haven't found a variation that'll work yet.

Comment: Wow, that rule is huge! `:)` If you use `<arara>`, there's no need to enclose the text in quotes. I think `curl` would behave better if you try something along the lines of `curl mywebsite.com?a=b'&'foo=bar` (note that I literally used `'&'` instead of enclosing the whole text in quotes).

Comment: Hello Paulo :) Yeah, huge, I do like what arara can do for me. I've updated the gist to what I think you said, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Hello! `:)` Ah thanks for reporting back. `:)` Could you provide a sample `.tex` document, even if via another gist? That way I can try for real. `:)`

Comment: I've added a minimal failing example in the comment to that gist. Thanks! This is on windows BTW.